# Handling multiple heads after graft

Tags: mercurial

First I had a repository:

```
A---B---C
```

I pulled some changes from another repo:

```
A---B---C
     \
      --D---E---F
```

Then I grafted necessary changes from another branch:

```
A---B---C---E'--F'
     \
      --D---E---F
```

Now I have 2 `default` branch heads. I want to continue working on the original.
What should I do with pulled head? Close it or leave it open? Are there any 
problems with either option in the future?

I don't have any problem having the other branch there. I may or may not pull and graft more changes in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem at all keeping the other head on the 'default' branch open.  Once you do another commit after F', say G', that will be the "newest" (technically "most tip-ward") head on 'default' so that's what you'll always get when you say "default" (example: `hg update default`).

If you want to close F you can do it with a 'hg commit --close-branch` but there's no need to do so.

Comment: There are no technical problems with unnamed branch but this is a little bit confusing for other users of repository.  I prefer merge in such situations.  Also, closing branch is a bad idea if author will pull changes from that repo in the future.  It is always strange when commits appear in closed branch :)